# docker: command not found Django channels

Tags: python, django, docker

I have just started with Django channels, and stuck at this error...

MacBook :chat $ docker run -p 6379:6379 -d redis:5

-bash: docker: command not found

Comment: do you have docker installed?

Comment: no man, how to do that .. i have mac machine

Comment: Install it from https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/install/